# Changing profile order and colors in TidyLPA plotting

Tags: r

Any ideas how I could simply change the colors and numbering of the profiles/classes from the outcome of TidyLPA's plot function? I want to do this because I am doing LPA analysis separately for two different datasets, which both produced a solution of two similar profiles (let's call them class 1 and class 2 as printed in the plot outcome). The problem is that the profiles are in different order in the outputs (so that class 1 is profile A in the first dataset, but class 2 in the second dataset), and I would like them to be consistent across datasets so that they would be easier to interpret for the reader.

Here is the code:

```
plot_profiles(lpa_results[["model_6_class_2"]],
+ ci = 0.95, sd = TRUE, add_line = TRUE, rawdata = TRUE, bw = FALSE, alpha_range = c(0, 0.1)
```

I tried to reverse the "class" here but it did not work:

```
lpa_results[["model_6_class_2"]][["dff"]][["Class"]]
```

This is the structure:

```
> str(lpa_results[["model_6_class_2"]])
List of 4
 $ model    :List of 19
  ..$ call           : language (function (data, G = NULL, modelNames = NULL, prior = NULL, control = emControl(), initialization = NULL, warn = | __truncated__ ...
  ..$ data           : num [1:993, 1:6] 5.5 6.5 4.5 4.98 6 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:993] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  ..$ modelName      : chr "VVV"
  ..$ n              : int 993
  ..$ d              : int 6
  ..$ G              : int 2
  ..$ BIC            : 'mclustBIC' num [1, 1] -16324
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "2"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "VVV"
  .. ..- attr(*, "G")= num 2
  .. ..- attr(*, "modelNames")= chr "VVV"
  .. ..- attr(*, "control")=List of 4
  .. .. ..$ eps     : num 2.22e-16
  .. .. ..$ tol     : num [1:2] 1.00e-05 1.49e-08
  .. .. ..$ itmax   : int [1:2] 2147483647 2147483647
  .. .. ..$ equalPro: logi FALSE
  .. ..- attr(*, "initialization")=List of 3
  .. .. ..$ hcPairs: 'hc' num [1:2, 1:992] 175 847 92 939 92 562 92 506 92 537 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "initialPartition")= num [1:993] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "unique")= int 993
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimensions")= int [1:2] 993 6
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "modelName")= chr "VVV"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "call")= language hc(data = data, modelName = mclust.options("hcModelName"), use = mclust.options("hcUse"))
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "use")= chr "SVD"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "data")= num [1:993, 1:6] -0.301 -0.321 -0.117 -0.167 -0.38 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:993] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ subset : NULL
  .. .. ..$ noise  : NULL
  .. ..- attr(*, "warn")= logi FALSE
  .. ..- attr(*, "n")= int 993
  .. ..- attr(*, "d")= int 6
  .. ..- attr(*, "oneD")= logi FALSE
  .. ..- attr(*, "criterion")= chr "BIC"
  .. ..- attr(*, "returnCodes")= num [1, 1] 0
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "2"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "VVV"
  ..$ loglik         : num -7972
  ..$ df             : num 55
  ..$ bic            : num -16324
  ..$ icl            : num -16595
  ..$ hypvol         : num NA
  ..$ parameters     :List of 3
  .. ..$ pro     : num [1:2] 0.372 0.628
  .. ..$ mean    : num [1:6, 1:2] 5.04 3.81 5.5 2.16 5.66 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ variance:List of 5
  .. .. ..$ modelName: chr "VVV"
  .. .. ..$ d        : int 6
  .. .. ..$ G        : int 2
  .. .. ..$ sigma    : num [1:6, 1:6, 1:2] 0.901 -0.664 0.554 -0.377 0.453 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ cholsigma: num [1:6, 1:6, 1:2] 0.949 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  ..$ z              : num [1:993, 1:2] 0.703 0.747 0.705 0.58 0.982 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:993] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  ..$ classification : Named num [1:993] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:993] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ uncertainty    : Named num [1:993] 0.297 0.2526 0.295 0.4203 0.0183 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:993] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ mclustBootstrap:List of 9
  .. ..$ G         : int 2
  .. ..$ modelName : chr "VVV"
  .. ..$ parameters:List of 3
  .. .. ..$ pro     : Named num [1:2] 0.372 0.628
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "1" "2"
  .. .. ..$ mean    : num [1:6, 1:2] 5.04 3.81 5.5 2.16 5.66 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ variance: num [1:6, 1:6, 1:2] 0.901 -0.664 0.554 -0.377 0.453 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ nboot     : num 100
  .. ..$ type      : chr "bs"
  .. ..$ nonfit    : num 0
  .. ..$ pro       : num [1:100, 1:2] 0.334 0.414 0.45 0.408 0.388 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "1" "2"
  .. ..$ mean      : num [1:100, 1:6, 1:2] 5.05 4.99 4.81 4.98 5.07 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "1" "2"
  .. ..$ variance  : num [1:100, 1:6, 1:6, 1:2] 0.772 1.061 1.043 0.94 0.836 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "1" "2"
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "MclustBootstrap"
  ..$ LRTS           : num 433
  ..$ LRTS_p         : num 0.0099
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "Mclust"
 $ fit      : Named num [1:18] 6 2 -7972 16054 16867 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:18] "Model" "Classes" "LogLik" "AIC" ...
 $ estimates:'data.frame':  54 obs. of  8 variables:
  ..$ Category : chr [1:54] "Means" "Means" "Means" "Means" ...
  ..$ Parameter: chr [1:54] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
  ..$ Estimate : num [1:54] 5.04 3.81 5.5 2.16 5.66 ...
  ..$ se       : num [1:54] 0.117 0.129 0.124 0.13 0.105 ...
  ..$ p        : num [1:54] 0.00 3.92e-192 0.00 1.37e-61 0.00 ...
  ..$ Class    : int [1:54] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ Model    : num [1:54] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
  ..$ Classes  : int [1:54] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ dff      : tibble [993 × 11] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ model_number  : num [1:993] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
  ..$ classes_number: int [1:993] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ AUT_SAT       : num [1:993] 5.5 6.5 4.5 4.98 6 ...
  ..$ AUT_FRU       : num [1:993] 3.75 3.75 4.75 3.81 2.75 ...
  ..$ COM_SAT       : num [1:993] 6.25 5.25 4.5 5.93 6 ...
  ..$ COM_FRU       : num [1:993] 1.5 1.75 2.75 3.18 1 ...
  ..$ REL_SAT       : num [1:993] 6.75 7 6.5 5.78 6 6 4 5.25 5 4.25 ...
  ..$ REL_FRU       : num [1:993] 2.25 1.75 1 1.84 1.25 ...
  ..$ CPROB1        : num [1:993] 0.703 0.747 0.705 0.58 0.982 ...
  ..$ CPROB2        : num [1:993] 0.297 0.2526 0.295 0.4203 0.0183 ...
  ..$ Class         : num [1:993] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "selected")= chr [1:6] "AUT_SAT" "AUT_FRU" "COM_SAT" "COM_FRU" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "tidyProfile.mclust" "tidyProfile" "list"
```